# Using randomisation of fixed effects for a psuedo-p in mcmc glmm

Tags: bayesian, p-value, glmm

I'm running generalized linear mixed models in R using the function `MCMCglmm()`, and with summary this generates p (pMCMC) values. However, pMCMC is, by the authors own admission, not perfect:

> ["pMCMC is the two times the smaller of the two quantities: MCMC estimates of i) the probability that a<0 or ii) the probability that a>0, where a is the parameter value. **Its not a p-value as such, and better ways of obtaining Bayesian p-values exist.**"](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2011q3/016822.html)

**To generate some sort of "p" value, could one randomise the fixed effects (maintaining the structure of the data) and re-run the glmm, repeat *n* times, and then give the ratio of randomised fixed estimates that are further from zero than the estimate from the actual data?** Has this approach been examined/utilised previously in citable literature?

---

**For an illustrative example**, a researcher might have 10 groups of 50 mice, which were exposed to *chemical X* in varying quantities. The quantity of *chemical X* varies among groups, but not within groups. The researcher then measures body weight, and analyses the effect of *chemical X* using glmm, where the quantity of *chemical X* is a fixed effect. The researcher then randomises the value of *chemical X* among groups, such that, when randomised, there is still no within group variance in exposure, and there is still among group variance, and the researcher then runs the glmm again, and repeats this process 1000 times. The researcher finds that 986 of the estimates for the fixed effect are closer to 0 than the actual estimate, and concludes that *chemical X* has a significant effect, with p = (1-(986/1000)) = 0.014 (this would be two tailed, because it's based on distance from zero, which is the absolute difference between zero and the estimate, e.g. -10 is further from zero than +2).