# Defining "p" value for glmm randomisation psuedo-p value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, p-value, markov-chain-montecarlo, glmm

I am currently using a Bayesian approach to glmm (`MCMCglmm` in R) to estimate regression coefficients ([see here where I ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221279/using-randomisation-of-fixed-effects-for-a-psuedo-p-in-mcmc-glmm) whether randomisation of fixed effects is a valid method). To test whether these are significant I am using a randomise-restimate-repeat process where the fixed effect is randomised and regression coefficient estimated 1000 ($n$) times. I want to check I have the correct understanding of the p value.

The way I interpret the p value is as the probability of getting the observed result by chance, if the null hypothesis was true. So with my process of randomisation, that would mean (to me) that if I perform 1000 randomisations, and the *absolute value* of my estimated coefficient is larger than the absolute value of 920 of my randomised estimates the p-value would be 920/1000 = 0.092.

- Because I am using absolute values, would this be a two-tailed test?
- If I instead wanted to do a one-tailed test, could I simply use the actual values (not use absolute) to show how many samples are less than (or greater than) my estimate?
- If I want to test when my null hypothesis does not = 0 (e.g. ratio of no difference would have a null hypothesis, $H_0$, of 1) could I calculate a p-value as the ratio of randomised samples further from $H_0$ than the observed result?

***In summary***, would a two-tailed test be accomplished by using the ratio of samples where the absolute value is greater than the value expected under the null hypothesis (and one tailed be the rate in a specific direction)?